# search words in adobe pdf reader in access 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007

I can see my pdf file

```
Private Sub Form_Load() 
Dim FILENAME As String  
FILENAME = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\abandon.pdf"  
AcroPDF5.LoadFile FILENAME  
End Sub
```

But I want search in my pdf and find abandon and show it on a label on a form.

Comment: "Searching text in a PDF" is a *very* broad topic.

Comment: my question is not obvious? I have a pdf file and I want to find a word (such as abandon) in it. How can I find a word in a pdf file with VBA in access 2007. Thank you.

Comment: Your question is obvious, but the answer is "too broad". Text in a PDF is not "normal text", as it is in a plain text file or (very) simple word processor formats. You need a good PDF parser at least (and even the best parsers cannot guarantee 100% reliable text extraction, for any PDF).

Comment: thank you. what is the solution? I must use picturs instead 
of pdf file? With thanks.